How to create a CPQ Promotion Product with dynamic Time Intervals and discount %?
I'm trying to create a Promotion Product that can be applied for a Product bundle in the quoting process, at the same time that allows the Sales rep to enter a dynamic discount period and %, more than 1 level. For example, 1st 3 months, customer gets 50% discount on MSRP, and for next 2 months 25% discount and 0% discount for the rest of the contract term.
